# How to read data custom attribute from DOM in jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to read the user id from "data-user-id" using jquery "data" api but I am not able to get the value of custom data attribute

```
var userId = $(".invited-user").data("user-id");
```

I try above jquery code but I am not get the user id

```
<div id="selected-items" style="display: block;"><div id="selected-items"><div class="selected-item"><span class="label label-info invited-user" data-user-id="51935d96db0cad4b290004c5">
    <span class="invited-user-name">
        Kumaran
    </span>
    <button class="btn btn-info remove-btn">x</button>
</span></div></div></div>
```

Please suggestion a jquery api to read the custom data attribute.

Comment: Confirmed working in a JSFiddle.

Comment: The code given appears to work fine if loaded into JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x9QJf/

Comment: yes it working fine... I dont why its not working first... thanks!

Comment: suppose if I have more than 1 data-user-id attribute how to find that?

Comment: You can't have duplicate attributes, only one of them will be used.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the complete code? The problem might be somewhere else .

Comment: question posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627707/how-to-find-duplicate-data-attributes-from-dom-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your HTML doctype. It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Check the javascript console for any possible errors
3. Check that the jquery library is included or not.